# Component is somehow rendering despite conditional statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On my `Home` component, on initial load, I loop through an object of URLs, and use `Promise.all` to make sure they all resolve at the same time. I construct an object, and push it into state. At the start of this I have `loading: true`, then set to `false` when done pushing that object into state:

`Home Component`:

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: null,
    movies: {
      trending: {},
      topRated: {},
      nowPlaying: {},
      upcoming: {}
    },
    loading: false
  };
componentDidMount() {
    this.getInitalMovies();       
  }
getInitalMovies = () => {
    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
    //set loading to true
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    //create an object with all movie URLs
    const allMovieURLs = {
      trending: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/day?api_key=${API_KEY}`,
      topRated: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
      nowPlaying: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
      upcoming: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`
    };

    //break down the movieURL object into entries, fetch the URL, and reassign entries with actual data
    //encapsulate within a Promise.all to ensure they all resolve at the same time.
    const moviePromises = Promise.all(
      Object.entries(allMovieURLs).map(entry => {
        const [key, url] = entry;
        return fetch(url).then(res => res.json().then(data => [key, data]));
      })
    );
    //with the returned promise from Promise.all, reconstruct the array of entries back into an object with relevant key pair values
    const movies = moviePromises.then(movieArr => {
      const dataObj = {};
      for (const [movie, movieData] of movieArr) {
        dataObj[movie] = movieData;
      }
      return dataObj;
    });
    //with the returned object, push it into current state, then turn off loading
    movies.then(movieObj =>
      this.setState({ movies: movieObj, loading: false })
    );
  };
 render() {
    const { movies } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Header
          submitHandler={this.submitHandler}
          changeHandler={this.changeHandler}
        />
        <HeroImage />
        {this.state.loading ? <Loader /> : <MovieDisplay movies={movies} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

`MovieDisplay` Component:

```
export default class MovieDisplay extends Component {
  render() {
    const { movies } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <MovieRow movies={movies.trending.results} movieType='trending' />
        <MovieRow movies={movies.topRated.results} movieType='top rated' />
        <MovieRow movies={movies.nowPlaying.results} movieType='now playing' />
        <MovieRow movies={movies.upcoming.results} movieType='upcoming' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`MovieRow` Component:

```
export default class MovieRow extends Component {
  render() {
    const { movieType, movies } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='row-title'>{movieType}</div>
        {console.log(movies)} //This part seems to somehow mount even when conditional rendering says it shouldn't!
        <Slider {...settings} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I then have the body do a conditional render like so, so that if the loading is complete (`loading: false`), then my `MovieDisplay` component should render, otherwise it's still loading, so show the `Loader` component.

I confimed that this part is working (if I search the React Devtools for `Loader` when `loading: false` it does **not** exist, but `MovieDisplay` **does** exist.

I'm passing down a data object via props from `Home` >  `MovieDisplay` > `MovieRow`, and then looping through the array to display more components.

However, on initial load, it seems the `MovieRow` (last, nested child component) is somehow being mounted for a quick second, because in the console it's logging 4 `undefined` statements briefly, before resolving with the proper data.

**Main question:** If the Parent Component is not rendered to the DOM, then the child components inside of the Parent should also not be rendered, right?

Secondary question: Is it possible that all the components in my app are rendering briefly for a second on initial load, despite having a conditional in the `render()` function? That's the only thing I can think of that's causing this.

Example: If `MovieDisplay` is not rendered, then everything inside of it like `MovieRow` should also not be rendered, correct?

Hope this isn't too confusing...please let me know if I need to edit my problem or elaborate.

Comment: I think `<MovieDisplay /> `'s `render` function will get called regardless of conditional. If you don't want it's render function to get called, then wrap in a lambda and conditionally invoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.then` does not resolve a promise. It lets you get the value after the promise was resolved

This is because of the asynchronous nature of JS. Initially, when componentDidMount is called, you set loading = true.

Before the promise is completed(loading = true) react renders the HOME component, this is the reason it calls MovieDisplay component.

Try adding an extra condition where you call MovieDisplay

```
 {this.state.loading && "check your data is filled in movies object" ? <Loader /> : <MovieDisplay movies={movies} />}
```

Comment: So your answer wasn't exactly working, but I found out the issue because you pointed out the asynchronous nature of the `Promise` call I made in `componentDidMount`. My conditional, for a millisecond, was not changing to `true`, because all of my code ran before my `Promise.all` finished. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
{this.state.loading && <Loader />} 
{!this.state.loading && <MovieDisplay movies={movies} />}
```